# Passing Range Names

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined several ranges , for example:

```
Sheets(“Customers”).Activate
Set MYR1 = Range(Cells(1,  1), Cells(1,  25))
Set MYR2 = Range(Cells(5,  1), Cells(5,  25))
Set MYR2 = Range(Cells(16,  1), Cells(16,  25))
```

In another procedure I have written the following code to search a range and process the result.  My problem is how do I call the Findany routine and pass the different ranges as required.

```
Sub Findany()
    Set foundrange =  MYR1.Find(what:=i)
    If foundrange Is Nothing Then
        Do Something
    Else
        Do Something Else
    End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
Sub Findany(rngToSearchIn As Range)    '<< argument in this line

    Set foundrange = rngToSearchIn.Find(what:=i)    '<<passed range used here
    If foundrange Is Nothing Then
        Do Something
    Else
        Do Something Else
    End If
```

When calling your `Findany` soubroutine use this:

```
Call Findany(MYR1)
```

or simply:

```
Findany MYR1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Function maybe easier:

```
Function Range1() As Range
    Set Range1 = Range("A1:C3")
End Function
```

Another range:

```
Function Range2() As Range
    Set Range2 = Range("A5:C7")
End Function
```

And so on...

Then the Findany sub:

```
Sub Findany(rng As Range, query As String)
    Set foundrange = rng.find(what:=query)
    If foundrange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally:

```
Sub Search()
Call Findany(Range2, "hello")
End Sub
```

Done!